# How to change theme in Watson Studio?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, ibm-watson, watson-studio, watson-studio-desktop

Is there a way to change theme in Watson Studio or in a notebook within? I know it can be done for OpenPages with Watson: https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/opw/8.2.0?topic=ui-themes but I couldn't find adequate options for the Watson Studio.

Answer (score 1):

this is not currently possible, but we're working on enabling a dark mode.